# Two-sided slider getting stuck

Tags: graphics, dynamic

I'm implementing a two-sided slider to be able to set upper and lower bound in just one slider:

[image]

The problem is that it can get stuck when both locators are at the far left:

[image]

And I'm unable to grab the blue locator.

```
SetAttributes[TwoSidedSlider, HoldAll];
TwoSidedSlider[sliderMin_, sliderMax_, var1_, var2_, 
  maxIsInfinity_: False] := DynamicModule[
  {pt = {{var1, 0}, {If[var2 == Infinity, sliderMax, var2], 0}}},
  LocatorPane[
   Dynamic[pt,
    ((* Update while dragging \*)
      pt = #1;
      var1 = #1[[1, 1]];
      var2 = 
       If[maxIsInfinity && #1[[2, 1]] == sliderMax, 
        Infinity, #1[[2, 1]]];
      ) &
    ],
   Graphics[{
     Gray, Line[{{sliderMin, 0}, {Dynamic[pt[[1, 1]]], 0}}],(* min to lower \*)
     Black, 
     Line[{{Dynamic[pt[[1, 1]]], 0}, {Dynamic[pt[[2, 1]]], 0}}], (* lower to upper \*)
     Gray, 
     Line[{{Dynamic[pt[[2, 1]]], 0}, {sliderMax, 0}}] (* upper to max \*)
     }, AspectRatio -> 1/5],
   { (* Locator Region and stepsize \*)
    {{sliderMin, 0},
     {Dynamic[pt[[2, 1]]], 0}, {1, 1}},
    {{Dynamic[pt[[1, 1]]], 0},
     {sliderMax, 0}, {1, 1}}
    }
   , Appearance -> {Style["[", Red, Larger, Bold], 
     Style["]", Blue, Larger, Bold]}]]
```

It is used something like this:

```
lower = 0; upper = Infinity;
{{Dynamic[lower], TwoSidedSlider[0, 5000, lower, upper, True], 
   Dynamic[upper]}} // TableForm
```

Any tips on how to get a two-sided slider or what causes this one to get stuck?

Comment: You might find the ``Experimental` `` context interesting: Needs@"Experimental`"; Experimental`IntervalSlider[Dynamic@z, {-10, 10}].

Comment: Yea, that's interesting! Thanks

Comment: @IstvánZachar how did you learn that? It seems to be undocumented (Experimental/guide/ExperimentalPackage)

Comment: @Mike: Yes, it is undocumented, but you can find an **Experimental** directory in the **AddOns\Packages** subdir, which made me to try to load it with `Needs`. And the rest was just trial and error. It is also mentioned [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/807/89).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
pt = Clip[#1\[Transpose]*{1, 0}, {sliderMin, sliderMax}]\[Transpose];
```

as the update function, and remove the min-max restrictions from the `LocatorPane` (3rd argument). Also, when you update `pt` based on `#1`, you should use `pt` instead of `#1` when you update `var1` and `var2`:

```
SetAttributes[TwoSidedSlider, HoldAll];
TwoSidedSlider[sliderMin_, sliderMax_, var1_, var2_, 
  maxIsInfinity_: False] := DynamicModule[
  {pt = {{var1, 0}, {If[var2 == Infinity, sliderMax, var2], 0}}},
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt, (
      pt = 
       Clip[#1\[Transpose]*{1, 0}, {sliderMin, sliderMax}]\[Transpose];
      var1 = pt[[1, 1]];
      var2 = 
       If[maxIsInfinity && pt[[2, 1]] == sliderMax, Infinity, 
        pt[[2, 1]]];
      ) &],
   Graphics[{Gray,
     Line[{{sliderMin, 0}, {Dynamic[pt[[1, 1]]], 0}}],
      Black, 
     Line[{{Dynamic[pt[[1, 1]]], 0}, {Dynamic[pt[[2, 1]]], 0}}],
      Gray, Line[{{Dynamic[pt[[2, 1]]], 0}, {sliderMax, 0}}]}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/5],
   (*{{{sliderMin,0},{var1,0},{1,1}},{{0,0},{sliderMax,0},{1,1}}},*)
   Appearance -> {Style["[", Red, Larger, Bold], 
     Style["]", Blue, Larger, Bold]}]]

lower = 0; upper = Infinity;
{{Dynamic[lower], TwoSidedSlider[0, 5000, lower, upper, True], 
   Dynamic[upper]}} // TableForm
```

Comment: Nope, with this it is possible to move the left slider over the right one.

Comment: That nearly works, with a pt = Sort[...] it does well

Comment: And with pt = Round[Sort[...],stepsize] it's perfect!

Comment: @halirutan: it wasn't stated that the first locator cannot have the larger value...

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that when the sliders have the same value, `Dynamic` chooses the wrong to move when you click near it. You could make the sliders have a small gap between them and it works as expected

```
SetAttributes[TwoSidedSlider, HoldAll];
TwoSidedSlider[sliderMin_, sliderMax_, var1_, var2_, 
  maxIsInfinity_: False] := 
 DynamicModule[{pt = {{var1, 
      0}, {If[var2 == Infinity, sliderMax, var2], 0}}}, 
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt, ((*Update while dragging *) pt = #1;
      var1 = #1[[1, 1]];
      var2 = 
       If[maxIsInfinity && #1[[2, 1]] == sliderMax, 
        Infinity, #1[[2, 1]]];) &], 
   Graphics[{Gray, 
     Line[{{sliderMin, 0}, {Dynamic[pt[[1, 1]]], 0}}],(*min to lower *) 
     Black, Line[{{Dynamic[pt[[1, 1]]], 0}, {Dynamic[pt[[2, 1]]], 
        0}}],(*lower to upper *) Gray, 
     Line[{{Dynamic[pt[[2, 1]]], 0}, {sliderMax, 0}}]
      (*upper to max *)}, AspectRatio -> 1/5], {
     (*Locator Region and stepsize *) {{sliderMin, 
      0}, {Dynamic[pt[[2, 1]] - 1], 0}, {1, 
      1}}, {{Dynamic[pt[[1, 1]] + 1], 0}, {sliderMax, 0}, {1, 1}}}, 
   Appearance -> {Style["[", Red, Larger, Bold], 
     Style["]", Blue, Larger, Bold]}]]
```

Note the change in the last argument to `LocatorPane`.